# Extension functions on annotated types

Tags: annotations, kotlin, kotlin-extension

Is it possible to define a Kotlin extension function on a annotated type like this?

```
@ColorInt
fun @ColorInt Int.darken(): Int {
    return ColorUtils.blendARGB(this, Color.BLACK, 0.2f)
}
```

Alternative form:

```
@ColorInt
fun (@ColorInt Int).darken(): Int {
    return ColorUtils.blendARGB(this, Color.BLACK, 0.2f)
}
```

That would correspond to the following static funtion:

```
@ColorInt
fun darken(@ColorInt color: Int): Int {
    return ColorUtils.blendARGB(color, Color.BLACK, 0.2f)
}
```

I don't think that's possible yet using Kotlin, but would it be possible to add that feature in later Kotlin versions?

On a side note:
The same question applies to `@IntDef`, `@StringDef`, `@[resource type]Res` as well.

Comment: zsmb13 had a good point explaining that this could cause some issues with doubled methods with the same signature. Anyway that could be solved by annotating a different JVM method name for that function.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Yes you can. Use the following syntax:

```
@ColorInt
fun @receiver:ColorInt Int.darken(): Int {
    return ColorUtils.blendARGB(this, Color.BLACK, 0.2f)
}
```

More about annotation use-site targets: http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets

Comment: That's brilliant! I guess IntelliJ would then automatically hide that extension function for methods that are not annotated `@ColorInt`, right?

Comment: No, `@ColorInt` is an android-specific annotation which is evaluated by Lint. Lint supports Kotlin code and you should get a warning when you call the method on an int which is not annotated, but you will still be able to call the method.

Comment: That would be as expected.

Comment: @Heinrich if that answer was helpful to you, please consider accepting it.

Comment: This method seems to be deprecated now; I get this lint warning: `Use of this annotation with target 'type' and use site target '@receiver' is deprecated.` Any alternatives?

Comment: @A.K.S.H. this seems to be a bug and should be fixed in 1.2.40: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-21696

Comment: What about `@DrawableRes`? that the function will return Drawable? Android studio will complain: `This annotation does not apply for type android.graphics.drawable.Drawable; expected int or long`

Comment: @HendraWD, `@DrawableRes` denotes a resource ID that holds a drawable ressource, not a `Drawable` itself.

Comment: Is this still working? I am doing this, but using layout res, string res, even with a negative number, there is no warning.